# How to change Joomla template

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have already searched for some website to get free template since I want to change joomla template. Is there anyone who knows where can i get FREE Joomla template? And how to change the template. Thank you

Comment: Free templates, unless from one of the large and well-respected commercial template providers, are the fastest way to a hacked site and a compromised sever. Be very, very, careful what you install on your site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to install a Joomla template**

**Installation steps**
After downloading the Joomla template go to Joomla administrator -> Extensions -> Extensions Manager.
[image: Joomla Administrator]

You will see the screen below
[image: Upload and install Joomla template]
Here you can upload the Joomla template zip file by clicking browse and locating the template file. After doing that click **Upload & Install**.

**Assign the template to your website**
Go to Joomla administrator -> Extensions -> Template manager -> Here you can see the new template. Click the star next to it to make it the default template for your website. 
[image: Assign template]

Note that if Administrator is written on the right of the star, the template will only show for the Administrative section of the website.

Comment: Ok Thank you @Jextn

Answer (score 5):

Before installing any *free* template, you should take a close look at the code as malicious code in the template can be used to take control of your website, and/or web hosting account or web server.

This question provides some tips for finding exploit code that can be hidden in free templates, and some advice on where to find reputable free templates:

[How can I tell if a free template contains malware?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/503/how-can-i-tell-if-a-free-template-contains-malware/523#523)

Answer (score 1):

Most commercial template providers offer one or more templates for free, as a way for you to test how the framework and template settings work. These are completely safe to use, and as far as I know they can be used for commercial sites too, without any restrictions. Some template clubs ([JoomlaShine](http://www.joomlashine.com/free-joomla-templates.html), for instance) has most of their templates available for free, but with limited functionality (fewer back-end settings and no responsive design).

In addition, I'd recommend [Joomla24.com](http://joomla24.com), they offer more than 4000 free Joomla templates, most of them from well-known template providers. The [Template Gallery](http://www.joomla24.com/index.php?set_albumName=album10&option=com_gallery&Itemid=6&include=view_album.php) is a good place to start looking. Just make sure you read through the terms of use, as many of the templates can only be used for non-commercial sites, or they do not allow you to remove the back-link to the author.

**NOTE**
Commercial templates (illegal copies) are also available for download on certain sites. As others have mentioned, these are *guaranteed* to contain hidden back-links and malicious code.